# Borel-Cantelli (proof and application)

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-verification, self-learning

Hi I was reading the second volume of the Tao's Analysis book and in one exercise he's asking for a proof of Borel-Cantelli

> If we have a sequence $s_n\in \Omega$ of measurable sets s.t. $\sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}} m(s_n)<\infty$. Then $M=\{x\in \Omega: x\in s_n \text{ infinitely often }\}$ has measure zero.

Here is my approach: Define $f=\sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}}1_{s_n}$, then

$$\int_\Omega f=\int_\Omega\sum_n1_{s_n}=\sum_n\int_\Omega1_{s_n}=\sum_nm(s_n)<\infty \tag1$$

Using the Lebesgue monotone convergence theorem in $\sum_{n\le N} s_n=S_N\le S_{N+1}\le \ldots$. So $\{x\in \Omega:f(x)=\infty\}$ has measure zero.  Since this set is the same as $M$ the claim follows.

> (2) Now in other point of the problem  where I'm stuck says. Let $p>2$ and $c>0$. Let $$\{x\in [0,1]\, : \, \rvert x-a/q \lvert\le c/q^p \text{ for infinitely many positive integers } a, q \}$$ has measure zero.

My first idea was something very naive:

$$A(a,q)=\left\{x\in [0,1]: \left|x-\frac{a}{q}\right|<\frac{c}{q^{p}} \ \text{ for } a\le q \right\}$$ So the set $A(a,q)$ consists of about $q$ intervals of size at most $2c/q^{p}$ from here since $c>0$ is a positive real we have $\sum_{q\in\mathbb N}|A(a,q)|<\infty$

Any ideas for the second point? I can't figure out how to use the Borel-Cantelli. I believe the sets are similar as $A(a,q)$ I really appreciate some extra-hint.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your argument for (1) sounds right.

For (2), you want to apply Borel-Cantelli, so what should the set $s_n$ be? Key estimate: there are at most $q-1$ reduced fractions with denominator $q$, and $\sum_q q/q^p < \infty$ since $p >2$.

Comment: Sorry I can't understand the relation for the second point.

Comment: The relation is that for a judicious choice of sets $s_n$ as in the Borel-Cantelli lemma, you will have $\sum m(s_n) = \sum_q \frac{q}{q^p} < \infty$.

Comment: My vague idea is something like: $$A(a,q)=\left\{x\in [0,1]: \left|x-\frac{a}{q}\right|<\frac{c}{q^{p}} \ \text{ for } a\le q \right\}$$ So the set $A(a,q)$ consists of about $q$ intervals of size at most $2c/q^{p}$ from here since $c>0$ is a positive real we have $\sum_{q\in\mathbb N}|A(a,q)|<\infty$ @Tony

Comment: Sounds like more than a "vague" idea!

Answer (score 1):

I think your proof of (1) is correct. Here is a proof of (1) without using integration nor any theorem. Write $\{s_{n_k}\}$ for the subsequence with $M\subset s_{n_k}$. Then, for any $k\in\mathbb N$,
$$
k\,m(M)\leq\sum_1^km(s_{n_j})\leq\sum_nm(s_n), 
$$
so
$$
m(M)\leq\frac1k\,\sum_nm(s_n).
$$
As $k$ is arbitrary, $m(M)=0$.

Comment: Thanks,very beautiful and simple argument.