# Borel-Cantelli lemma and related question

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> Let $p > 2$ and $c>0$. Using the Borel-Cantelli lemma, show that the set 
>   $$\{x \in [0, 1]: |x - \frac{a}{q}| \le \frac{c}{q^p} \text{for infinitely many positive integers $a, q$}\}$$ 
>   has measure zero. (Hint: one only has to consider those integers $a$ in the range $0 \le a \le q$, and use that the sum $\sum_{q=1}^\infty \frac{c(q+1)}{q^p}$ is finite.)

The same question is asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1008502/borel-cantelli-proof-and-application). But, I have some difficulty in understanding the gap between hint and proof.

First, why is it sufficient to consider the range of $a$ from $0$ to $q$?

Also, in this link, the user consider the set $A(a, q) = \{x \in [0, 1] : |x - \frac{a}{q}| \le \frac{c}{q^p} \text{for  $a \le q$} \}$. Then, why $m(A(a, q)) = \frac{c(q+1)}{q^p}$? Shouldn't it just be $\frac{2c}{q^p}$?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your first question: It is sufficient to only consider $0 < a \leqslant q$ because otherwise $a/q > 1$, and in this case there will only be *finitely* many $q$ such that

$$ 
\left\lvert x - \frac{a}{q} \right\rvert \leqslant \frac{c}{q^p}
$$

since $ 0 \leqslant x \leqslant 1$.

**EDIT/CLARIFICATION:** What I mean is that if

$$\frac{a}{q} - 1 \geqslant \frac{1}{q} > 0,$$

then for any $x \in \left[ 0, 1 \right]$, the condition implies that

$$\frac{1}{q} \leqslant \left\lvert x - \frac{a}{q} \right\rvert \leqslant \frac{c}{q^p} < \frac{c}{q^2}.$$

There are at most finitely many $q$ that can satisfy this.

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite get your first point. Even if $a  \le q$, it is still true that $c q^{-p} \to 0$ as $q \to \infty$.

Comment: No problem. I edited to elaborate a bit on what I mean.